# $X-Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are sums of Bernoulli random variables

Tags: st.statistics, bernoulli-trial

Let $X = x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n$ and $Y = y_1 + y_2 + \ldots + y_n$, where each $x_i$ is an independent Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p_i$ and each $y_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $q_i$. In addition, suppose that $\sum_i p_i = c +\sum_j q_j$ for some constant $c>5$. My question is, whether or not the inequality $$ \mathbb{P}(X-Y =2) \geq \mathbb{P}(X-Y=1) $$ always holds?

Comment: Do you assume that all random variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n,y_1,\ldots,y_n$ are independent?

Comment: Yes, all the variables are independent.

Comment: I guess $X$ and $Y$ are what's known as "Poisson binomial" random variables, and the question is basically whether a difference of two independent Poisson binomials is unimodal.

Comment: Do you have investigated the limiting case that $X \sim Po(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim Po(\lambda-c)$ with $c > 5$ and $\lambda > 5$ and $X,Y$ independent? What if you replace $c$ by some smaller value?

Comment: It seems that it  is valid for the limiting cases. While I was searching for the correct answer, I found the following series of results: 1- both $X$ and $Y$ are unimodal and log-concave (https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0581.pdf) and 2- when one distribution is unimodal while the other one is log-concave, their difference is also unimodal (statement in the proof of proposition 7 in paper "Precision May Harm: The Comparative Statics of Imprecise Judgement."). Is it correct?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: Does unimodality necessarily implies the inequality?